# Select entries where now between startDate and endDate

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to select entries where now is between startDate and endDate but it it doesn't work and I have no error apears with this query

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->Where(':now BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
        ->setParameter('startDate', 'c.startDate')
        ->setParameter('endDate', 'c.endDate')
        ->setParameter('now', new \Datetime())
        ->orderBy('c.id', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I have changed the query like this and it works now:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->Where(':now BETWEEN c.startDate AND c.endDate')
        ->setParameter('now', new \Datetime())
        ->orderBy('c.id', 'DESC');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: What query is this producing, can you run it directly (or via phpmyadmin)?

Comment: @kingkero it was a mistake and lack of concentration from me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');

$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.startDate < :now')
        ->andWhere('c.endDate > :now')
        ->setParameter('now', new \Datetime())
        ->orderBy('c.id', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: thank you , your code work and I have also changed the query `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->Where(':now BETWEEN c.startDate AND c.endDate')
            ->setParameter('now', new \Datetime())
            ->orderBy('c.id', 'DESC');`